# How to pull all of a members servers in EJS/DJS?

Tags: node.js, express, discord.js, ejs

In my discord bots dashboard, I am looking to pull all of the servers that the member is in so I can have the member manage those servers, but, every thing I have tried refuses to work and I no longer know what to do here. Here is the code:

```js
user.guilds.forEach(guild => {
    //const permsOnGuild = guild.permissions;
    //if(!user.guild.hasPermission('MANAGE_GUILD')) return;
    if(!guild.members.cache.get(user.id).hasPermission('MANAGE_GUILD')) return;

// Do a ton here for the servers.
)}
```

The error I continue getting:
Regarding the actual snippit I am trying to run, which can't get the user, can't read the cache of undefined, can't read nothing I do and doesn't even work, it worked a long time ago (Little over 6 months when I first tried developing a dashboard). If anybody could help that would be FANTASTIC.

Comment: Can you tell us what `user` is?

Comment: Are you using something such as passport-discord that will attach a `guilds` property to `req.user`? Is `user` a plain `User` object (in which case, it doesn't have a `guilds` property)?

Comment: I am using discord passport,I have been for a little bit so still iffy about it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure what you are asking for but I suppose you're meaning to check if any members have manage guild in a server.

```js
var guild = message.guild; // You can change this
guild.members.fetch() // Fetches members first to avoid gateway intent problems
guild.members.cache.forEach(member=>{
  if(!member.hasPermission('MANAGE_GUILD')) return;
  // Do anything here as you like!
})
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Did and didn't, my goal was for a web dashboard, I was able to get in touch with someone that was able to help me out and actually got it figured out!
Edit: 
Still, wonderful answer! People would love to see this regardless.

Comment: Oh, sorry it didn't help, glad to help other people!